# How can I reject an Edit which I have just Approved?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have just approved a [Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) but realized I should have in fact reject it. I am able to click back to the aprroval page but am not sure how I can amend my approval of the edit. Does anyone have experience in this?

(excluding tests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't go back and change your suggested edit decision. If you find that you approved an edit too fast and missed something that can also be corrected, your best bet is to make that edit yourself.

Beyond that... just make a mental note for the future and be more careful when reviewing to minimize the chance of accidental approvals.

Comment: Thanks. It will be cool to have a 30 seconds undo window though, just like voting.

Comment: @George voting can be reversed any time, after an edit. If you mean close vote, it can also be retracted any time, not only for 30 seconds as far as I know.